# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin.Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.' header is present on the requested resource error

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors, laravel-5.3

I am trying to call my API (which is in `Laravel framework`) from `angular`. so, it fired a error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/inquiry. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

**this is my angular code**

```
var app = angular.module('inquiryForm', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {};

    // calling our submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
     alert(JSON.stringify($scope.user));
     var data=JSON.stringify("sameer");
    // Posting data to php file
     $http({
       method  : 'POST',
       url     : 'http://**.**.**.**/inquiry',
       data    : $scope.user,
       headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'}
     }).success(function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
     });
   }    
});
```

*Actully i am calling to one route which is in laravel (consider ip address for **.**.**.** in above url)*

**and my laravel route is:**
Route::post('inquiry', 'inquiryController@store');

**And this is my controller**

class inquiryController extends Controller
{
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data=$requst->all();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}

Comment: How are you running your application?

Comment: umm, Actully I am running it on chrome

Comment: No are you running your index.html in a web server or you are directly opening it in your web browser?

Comment: No, I am running index.html from local machine as well as from digital ocean but the error is same. And on digital ocean there is a nginx web server which serves my contents.

Comment: please, anybody help

Answer (score 0):

This error normally occurs when your java-script code tries to send a http request which is hosted in another domain or process. The browser won't allow Cross Origin requests as part of security feature. So you have to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)in your web service back-end. Please see below link and try it.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: How are you hosting your front-end and back-end applications ? Can you host both applications in a single hosting server.

Comment: yes, my frontend and my backend is on same server but my frontent runs on 80 port and my backend runs on 8080 port

Comment: Is it possible for you to run both apps on port 80 ?

Comment: I am coder with java background and also used apache to host php applications. I believe that you are serving PHP and plain html files. Which server are you using to host or debug php application ? Add the same html and js file in your API directory and access it from there. I think apache can serve php scripts and html files.

Comment: but the thing is, i want to part the api from frontend. so thats why i have put it on different ports because my api is common for android app, ios app and webapp

Comment: I got your requirement. I also made an API to server multiple platforms and hosted in Google App Engine. The back-end was java though. But I got the same error that you got and it was resolved by enabling CORS in API code.

Comment: ok. so do you know how to do it in laravel 5.3?? because the link which you have given is only valid for laravel 5 i think.

Comment: I am not sure, what is blocking in your code. However I got below point from the above url.                                                                                  A simple but hacky method is to just always send the CORS headers. This isn't recommended for production, but it will show you the actual errors.

Add this to the top of public/index.php:

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": 'http://**.**.**.**/inquiry',
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": $.param($scope.user)  // angular may throw error bcz of $.param() method, then u have to use noConflict method and avoid $ symbol
                                          //Example: var jq = $.noConflict(); and use jq.param($scope.user)
        }
        $http(settings).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data.data);
        });
    }
});

or

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": 'http://**.**.**.**/inquiry',
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": $.param($scope.user)  // angular may throw error bcz of  $.param() method, then u have to use noConflict method and avoid $ symbol
        }
        /* http callback method*/
        $http(settings)then(function successCallback(data) {
                         console.log(data.data);
                    }, function errorCallback(err){
                        console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

now this should work....

Comment: i think problem with only POST request right, try to make jquery AJAX call and check it

Comment: i did one thing , i added one chrome extention "cors" and when it is enable it run successfully. this extention add two headers in my request "Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* " so how can i add this header with angular controller?

Comment: use angular Interceptors concept to modify your request and request header before sending to server http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/